# Redux Toolkit createSlice reducer type errors

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to create a new React-Redux project with Typescript. Everything has been great so far (albeit I haven't done much). I've got a reasonable level of React and Redux experience, however, it's out of date and this is my first delve into Redux toolkit as well. Coming from a typed background I've enjoyed with types in React, until I got to Slices.

I want to load most of the applications configuration from an API. So I have attempted to define and initial state (`initState`) and a fully loaded state (`ConfigurationState`). Everything seems ok, however, the reducer that would handle the configuration success action doesn't seem to know about the type `ConfigurationState`.

I'm working in WebStorm and getting the error `TS2339: Property 'authClientId' does not exist on type 'SliceState'.   Property 'authClientId' does not exist on type 'initState'.` for all the properties that should be defined in the `ConfigurationState` type.

I have been working off the example at [RTK Defining the initial state](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript#defining-the-initial-state-type) and I have tried various combinations of its example. Below is my current reducer.

Is there anything I'm doing obviously incorrect here?

```
// The state we expect until configuration is loaded from the API
type initState = {
    configurationApi?: string;
    configurationId?: string;
    loading: LoadingState;
};

// The full state we expect once configuration is loaded.
type ConfigurationState = {
    configurationApi: string;
    configurationId: string;
    authClientId: string,
    authDomain: string,
    authPoolId: string,
    authRedirectSignIn: string,
    authRedirectSignOut: string,
    authRegion: string,
    loading: LoadingState;
};

// Slice state can be either our initial preloaded state, or fully loaded state.
// See https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript#defining-the-initial-state-type
type SliceState = initState | ConfigurationState;

const initialState = {
    configurationApi: process.env.REACT_APP_CONFIGURATION_API,
    configurationId: process.env.REACT_APP_CONFIGURATION_ID,
    loading: LoadingState.IDLE,
} as initState;

const configurationSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'configuration',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        loadConfigurationStart(state) {
            if (state.loading !== LoadingState.PENDING) {
                state.loading = LoadingState.PENDING;
            }
        },
        loadConfigurationSuccess(state: SliceState, action: PayloadAction<ConfigurationState>) {
            state.loading = LoadingState.SUCCEEDED;
            state.authClientId = action.payload.authClientId;
            state.authDomain = action.payload.authDomain;
            state.authPoolId = action.payload.authPoolId;
            state.authRedirectSignIn = action.payload.authRedirectSignIn;
            state.authRedirectSignOut = action.payload.authRedirectSignOut;
            state.authRegion = action.payload.authRegion;
        }
    }
});

const { loadConfigurationStart, loadConfigurationSuccess } = configurationSlice.actions;

export default configurationSlice.reducer;
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass your `initialState as SliceState`, or better yet, `initialState satisfies SliceState as SliceState,` (as that is more typesafe)

```
const configurationSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'configuration',
    initialState: initialState satisfies SliceState as SliceState,
    reducers: {
```

After that point, you are down to normal TypeScript behaviour. Assume this code:

```
function someFunction(state: SliceState) {
  state.authClientId = "foo" // this will error
}
```

That is because `state` at this point could be `InitState` (which doesn't allow for `authClientId`), or `ConfigurationState`.

At that point, you can only add all those properties to your `InitState` as optional values, which kinda makes your `InitState` type pretty pointless in the first place. (To be honest, it seems pointless to me from the start).

Comment: Thank you for the response @phry. I added that and still have the same error. Could it be something in my `tsconfig.ts` or project setup? From the examples I can see I _think_ I'm doing it correctly and your suggestion also makes sense, so I'm a bit lost on this one.

Comment: I added some explanation for that!

Comment: Thanks for that. The optional value thing was what I was aiming to avoid. Initially I won't have those values and once I loaded, I want to make sure they are as expected. What I've done for in the mean time is i've abstracted the auth config into an `AuthConfiguration` type. I've made that optional on the SliceState. Once that loads in I can set those values in a way that ensures I have the correct properties and types by using the `AuthConfiguration` type and assigning that to the SliceState. At least then I either don't have the config and need to load it, or I have the config that I expect.